# 2 PHP arrays for merge

Tags: php, arrays, string, array-filter

How to delete element from array as it has partial in another?

Other words, I need to  compare 2 array likely `in_array` php function, but partially.

Code:

```
$a = ['abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'hi'];
$b = ['bce', 'ifg', 'hig'];
// return $b without 'hig' because in $a has partially 'hi'
```

Thanks very much for any solution!

Comment: Please clear your question what you want to do delete or compare?

Comment: Your question must have minimum and viable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make any string in `$b` not have any string in `$a` as a substring. **[demo](https://eval.in/938663)**

```
<?

$a = ['abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'hi'];
$b = ['bce', 'ifg', 'hig'];

$b = array_filter($b, function($v) use($a){ 
    foreach($a as $str){
      if(strpos($v, $str) !== false)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the array with anonymous function. Then a combination of [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to compare each letters of each elements. This works even if the letters on the element of `$a` array is shuffled

```
$a = ['abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'hi'];
$b = ['bce', 'ifg', 'hig'];

$b = array_filter($b, function($bElem) use($a) {
    foreach ($a as $aElem) {
        $diff = array_diff(
            str_split($aElem),
            str_split($bElem)
        );
        if (empty($diff)) return false;
    }
    return true;
});

print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, yuo want to compare start of string from $b with full string from $a

```
$b = array_udiff($b, $a, 
         function($x, $y) { return strcmp(substr($x, 0, strlen($y)), $y); });
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/938658)

Answer (score 0):

`Loop` through the array and look for `match`. If doesn't match any elements of the array, then `push` the value.

```
$a = ['abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'hi'];
$b = ['bce', 'ifg', 'hig'];
$result = $a;
foreach ($b as $bs) {
    $flag = true;
    foreach ($a as $as) {
        if (strpos($bs, $as) !== false) {
            $flag = false;
        }
    }
    if($flag==true)
        array_push($result, $bs);
}


return $result;
```